# How is "burial" incorrectly formed?

Tags: etymology, suffixes, word-formation, middle-english

*OED* says that:

> Middle English *buryel, biriel*, **incorrectly formed as a singular of *byriels***, *buriels* n., q.v.; in later times associated with nouns in *-al* from French, such as *espousal-s*.

[*Etymonline.com*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/burial) says that:

> "act of burying," late 13c.; earlier "tomb" (c. 1200), **false singular from Old English *byrgels*** "tomb," from *byrgan* "to bury" + suffix *-els*;

<sub><sup>*emphasis mine*</sup></sub>

How is the word *burial* incorrectly formed? What would be the correct form if it wasn't incorrectly formed?

---

According to *OED*, *buriels* was used but it is obsolete now.

Here is the etymology of *buriels* from OED:

> Old English *byrgels* strong masculine, cognate with Old Saxon *burgisli* neuter, < *burg-* ablaut-stem of *bergan* bergh n. to protect + suffix *-isli*- ; compare Old English *græfels* quarry, *fætels* purse, etc.

Comment: I think it means that *OE byrgels/byriels* was a false singular (ending with an s) and burial  incorrectly lost the final s on the model of French terms ending in -al which on thier turn took an s in the plural. In other words the singular form of those French terms influenced the spelling of burial by dropping the final s.

Comment: It must be pointed out that 'false singular' and 'incorrectly formed' apply solely to the technicalities of etymology, not to the correctness or otherwise of the words 'burial' and 'burials' today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the *OED*'s definition of [***buriels***](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/24975)<sup>1</sup>, namely

> 1. A burying-place; a sepulchre, tomb.
> 2. An interment, funeral.

Note that both meanings are already singular: ***A*** burying-place, ***An*** interment, etc.

So the "correct" formation of *burial* would be *buriels*. It was "falsely" constructed because the singular, Old English word was mistakenly believed to be a plural, French word. From the OED's etymology of [*burial*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/24969) (just after the part you cited):

> in later times associated with nouns in *-al* from French, such as *espousal-s*.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>"ˈburiels, n." *OED Online*, Oxford University Press, June 2017, www.oed.com/view/Entry/24975. The etymology of *buriels* is helpful in pointing out how a singular English word ended up ending in -s (among other things).  Note that the OED Online is unfortunately a prescription service (behind a paywall). However, many folks, especially in the UK, will have access through their local public library, and most students should be able to access through their institution's library. More info here: http://public.oed.com/about/free-oed/</sub>

<sup>2</sup> <sub>"burial, n." OED Online, Oxford University Press, June 2017, www.oed.com/view/Entry/24969.</sub>